# .NET solution failed to rebuild, claiming missing DLL, although it is there

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

Pulling my hear about this problem:
Platform - Windows 10 enterprise.
I have .NET solution with single startup project. The project is a Windows application.
The solution contains many projects. When trying to rebuild the solution, a project may failed claiming that ***specific namespace or type does not exists***. Lets call it ***Logger***.
The ***Logger*** is a project in the solution and it is compiled to a runtime folder as a (dotnet) dll.

Many projects in the solution has that dll as a project reference.

If I rebuild only the project that "complained" about the problem - it rebuild successfully.
The main problem is that after every new rebuild done to the solution - a different project is "complain" about that specific (**Logger**) dll. I can see the reference to the **Logger** dll in every problematic project.

when I delete the ***obj*** folder, the solution rebuild successfully.
I would like to use a defined ci\cd process, so deleting the obj folder is less preferred solution.

What could be the reason to that problem ?

Comment: assuming you run a solution build from the commandline, add `/v:diag`  to your msbuild commandline to get a full log. That should reveal where the compiler is looking for assemblies.

Comment: Is the solution and its projects .NET (aka .NET Core) or .NET Framework? Are all the projects targeting the same framework version, e.g. .NET 7.0? When you say "a runtime folder" do you mean a folder like `Logger\bin\Debug\net7.0`?

Comment: @Jonathan Dodds - this is basically a .NET framework project, not .NET code, and it contains projects with some versions, starting 4.0 until 4.7.2 or 4.8. The runtime folder is a folder that all the projects targeting their output to (yes, like you mentioned, but not under the bin folder)

Comment: @rene - thanks - I'll check it

Comment: @GuyE Because the projects are using a common output folder and because they are targeting different framework versions, one possible issue is that the Logger project is being built multiple times via the `ProjectReference`s (but for different framework versions) and the Logger.dll is being overwritten in the common folder. If this is what is happening, you should be able to see it in the diagnostic log.